# How do I change the label style?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

i want to know if someone can help me to solve this problem.

I have a `checkbox` and when this is **checked**, the `combo` that is under, should be change his `labelField` from **normal** to **bold**, but, this is not working with the:

```
Ext.applyIf(force, {
    labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;' 
});
```

And this is the fiddle example: [FiddleSencha Example.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bs3)

Answer (score 0):

[`labelStyle`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-labelStyle) is a config option, which means that it isn't guaranteed that changing it after the component has been instantiated has the desired or any other effect.

There are basically three kinds of config options:

- Some have a distinguished setter method, e.g. [`fieldLabel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-fieldLabel) / [`setFieldLabel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-method-setFieldLabel)
- Some config options can be set using the generalized [`setConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-method-setConfig) method.
- Some cannot be changed once the component has been instantiated - in worst case, you would have to destroy the old component and create a new one.

I don't find a `setLabelStyle` method in the docs - but you should try whether your config option can be changed using `setConfig`, or not.

If you would have to destroy and create the component, you can instead try the following: The [`component.labelEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-property-labelEl) property (property, not config option!) contains the [`Ext.dom.Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) of the label. You should be able to use [`setStyle`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-setStyle) on it after the element has been created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `force.labelEl.dom.style.fontWeight` property to bold label.

Please refer running example on link [Style for combo field](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bsu)